# How do you access the Blender underline keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: interface, shortcut

In Microsoft office software if you press alt, menu items appear with a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible in Blender?

In this instance I was trying to select several edge loops with a combination of keys.

Comment: How were you going to show Blender which edge loops you were going to select if without mouse ? And I don't think you can get that behaviour like in Windows programs; Alt is used in another way in Blender. The only similar thing is that if you enter menu (e.g. Specials in Edit mode) it has underlined characters in its list items which show which button to press for fast access.

Comment: sorry, I would have had to start it all off with ctrl+alt+right click to select edge rings. Basically trying to do the following link with more shortcuts https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU

Comment: What? How to select an edge ring or edge loop? If that's the point, it's a totally different question... removed my answer. Please don't waste other people time and improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the space bar you get a search tool where you could search the name of the required operation and it show the shorcut of it (if it has a shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

Forementioned Searh command menu is the easyiest way if you know the command name. But if you don't you need to try opening every common dropdown menu look for you command to see if it has a hotkey. For you particular question about edge loops you first need to select at least one edge in every edge loop you want to select while being in edge selection mode(which can be toogle by **Ctrl+Tab** then **2**) , then the default hotkey would be **Ctrl+e** then **p**. You can check other hotkeys by opening other commond menus in mesh mode like **Ctrl+e, Ctrl+f, Ctrl+v** and **W** and by clicking **View,Select,Add,Mesh** buttons in bottom left corner of 3d window.[image]